# Music engraving - note with two accidentals - natural (♮) and sharp (♯)

Tags: lilypond, accidentals, engraving

I have a cello score here from [Sebastian Lee; Op. 70](https://imslp.org/wiki/40_Easy_Etudes_for_Cello,_Op.70_(Lee,_Sebastian)).

**Nr. 37** in `bass clef` and the key of `c minor` contains the following part:

[image]

what is the sense of this 5th note in the upper staff?
why is it using a natural (♮) and a sharp (♯)?

How would I call this note for engraving with [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org)?

I used this `code` for now:

`b(-3 g) g g ais-2 g-0 b(-3 g) g g ais-2 g | %05`

but this would give a result like this:

[image]

or is the extra `natural` only a warning, that is not necessarily needed?
[Sebastian Lee, Op.70 in LilyPond format on GitHub](https://github.com/nathanaelmeister/Lee-_Sebastian_-_Op.70_-_40_Easy_Etudes_for_Cello)

Comment: When excerpting scores, you *must* include the clefs and key signature, otherwise all answers are reduced to speculation.

Comment: @KilianFoth hey man, thanks for the feedback! I updated my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The note with the two accidentals is an A#. The B has a natural, showing that the key sig has at least one flat. I guess it has at least 3 flats, so As are flat unless otherwise stated? There used to be a convention that if, say, the key sig makes As flat, and you want an A#, you put a natural and a sharp, as shown in your extract. (Modern practice is to just put the sharp.)

Comment: IIRC, there's one situation where modern practice _might_ put a natural before a sharp: when the note would otherwise be a _double_ sharp.  (Usually from an accidental earlier in the bar, though I suppose it's technically possible it could be in the key signature.)

Comment: Note that this is done for readability -- the composer wanted to use both the B natural and the B flat (A sharp) more than once in the same measure, and this notation makes it much more intuitive for a performer to read, as opposed to using alternating natural and flat symbols on the same staff note.

Comment: The modern consensus is that natural signs immediately before other accidentals should *never* be used no matter what the context. A # in front of an f means an f sharp and can't possibly mean anything else.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in Rosie F's answer, the natural is not typically required here in modern notation.  But if you wanted to get it in Lilypond, I don't think there's a default accidental setting that will display these in this circumstance.  Instead, you probably will need to use the `Accidental.restore-first` property.  Something like:

```
b(-3 g) g g 
\tweak Accidental.restore-first ##t
ais-2 g-0 b(-3 g) g g ais-2 g
```

That can get you the extra natural sign if you'd want it:

[image]

Comment: I just found an article in the [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org) docs on [Automatic accidentals](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-pitches#automatic-accidentals). Just for the records :-)

Comment: @nath: yes, that's what I was referring to in terms of Lilypond's "default accidental settings."  There are a bunch of options there, but I'm not sure that any of them include this particular type of extra natural.